# How to upgrade Apache Kafka 2.0 to Apache Kafka 2.6 in running environment?

Tags: apache-kafka

we are using Apache kafka 2.0 in our production environment and now we are planning to upgrade the kafka version to 2.6 from 2.0

we are running in three broker based cluster setup

i am having the below questions.

1)is it possible to upgrade the kafka from one version to higher version?

2)while upgrading is there any data loss happen?

3)is it possible to perform while the cluster is running?

4)How to rollback to the down version if something wrong happened?

can you share your valuable thoughts for this question..

it would be helpful to setup..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, upgrades are possible - http://kafka.apache.org/26/documentation.html#upgrade

Data that's already written to the topics shouldn't get lost if you follow the guide. Active clients might experience network exceptions, retries, and potential dropped packets while individual brokers are restarting.

A rolling upgrade is possible to prevent downtime

Depending on the exact version, rollbacks are not possible due to internal log format changes (as indicated in the documentation)